# All the routes not loaded in Ember js 1.11

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to migrate an ember application from 1.10 to 1.11.4 (I'm on the way to upgrade the ember to the latest version). When I have upgraded the ember version most of the routes are not initialized (some did). Error on the console says "The route ... was not found". Also if I check using ember inspector most of the routes are not there. Working fine with 1.10.

Quite new to ember, tried for couple of days without any luck.Need some help from some experienced ember guys.

Comment: I'm using ember-data "1.0.0-beta.18"

Comment: Can you share your router.js?

Comment: I have fixed it.
In the application routes was defined in several places. 
For example:
In contacts.js.....
App.Router.map(function(){
this.route("user", {path: "/user/:id"},  function() {
this.route("contacts");
});
});

and in history.js.....
App.Router.map(function(){
this.route("user", {path: "/user/:id"},  function() {
this.route("history");
});
});

for some reason only one got loaded(or overridden). I have moved everything to one higher file and it started working. But it was working fine until 1.10